# pip install saxonche v 12.1.0 produces FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, saxon

On Windows10 in a brand new virtual environment created with Python 3.11.2

```
python -m venv effnve
```

I activated the VE and then did

```
pip install saxonche
```

as per saxonche's [homepage](https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/).

Every time I now start python, I get:

```
Error processing line 1 of C:\ff\effnve\Lib\site-packages\_preload_saxonche_12.1.0.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<frozen site>", line 186, in addpackage
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
  FileNotFoundError: .load-order-saxonche-12.1.0 not found

Remainder of file ignored
```

The file `.load-order-saxonche-12.1.0` is right there in `C:\ff\effnve\Lib\site-packages`

I tried tweaking `_preload_saxonche_12.1.0.pth`, to no avail. For the sake of completeness here it is, with my tweaks designated in the comments.

```
import sys; exec("
import ctypes
import os
import site

is_pyinstaller = getattr(sys, 'frozen', False) and hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS')

for d in site.getsitepackages():
    # the above line will retrieve ['C:\ff\effnve', 'C:\ff\effnve\Lib\site-packages']
    # so it'll always fall down the else-clause, hence 
    # tweak 1: start only if you have a path with site-packages 
    if 'site-packages' in d: 
        load_order_filepath = os.path.join(d, '.load-order-saxonche-12.1.0')
        
        if os.path.isfile(load_order_filepath):
            with open(load_order_filepath) as file:
                load_order = file.read().split()
            for lib in load_order:
                lib_path = os.path.join(d, lib)
                if not is_pyinstaller or os.path.isfile(lib_path):
                    ctypes.WinDLL(lib_path)
                    print(ctypes.WinDLL(lib_path))    # tweak: check it loads all 3 dll's. 
#                break    # tweak: this break was originally 8 eight spaces from start of line. Why?
#                         # Do you only need the first dll? Don't understand.  
        else:   # tweak: this else was originally at the start of the line. Why? 
            if not is_pyinstaller:        
                raise FileNotFoundError('.load-order-saxonche-12.1.0' + ' not found')
                print(d) # tweak to find out what it did not find. 
")
```

I would post this as a issue on GitHub or the like, but I couldn't find any other place to share this, that's why I'm posting it here.

The reason for using `saxonche` is that I need a Python library that supports XSLT 2.0.

Comment: This is a known and resolved issue in SaxonC 12.1 Python package/wheel for Windows, somehow the underlying build infrastructure components got unintentionally updated and introduced some unwanted loading of that file; you will need to live with the error if you want to use 12.1 on Windows at this time or use 12.0 instead or wait for 12.2 where the issue https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5934 is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/ has 12.2 now which should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes saxonche 12.2 is out which resolves this problem. Please let us know how it goes.

Comment: @ond1 Yes, seems fixed now. Thanks!